# Access to interstitial space from new work air-tight recessed lights (Halo H995ICAT)

Tags: ceiling, recessed-lighting

Short question: Is there a (reversible) way of getting access to the interstitial space in the ceiling through new work air-tight recessed lights, Halo H995ICAT in my case?

Longer question: I'm working out how to run speaker wire for in-ceiling speakers that will be at least 10 feet from the nearest wall. The ceiling is untextured drywall with matte paint, so cutting access holes isn't a very attractive option. There are 4 recessed lights along the run the to wall which would make this job pretty straightforward if I could get 'out' of them. I understand this is essentially counter to the purpose of AT recessed lighting, but given the easy access non-AT lighting of the olden days afforded, I'm surprised I haven't found much of any discussion of this predicament.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the need to be able to access the associated junction box, most such fixtures I've had experience with can, in fact, be taken apart through the hole in the ceiling far enough to do that, and in that case you'd have access to the interstitial space. You'll want to take pictures and use something to keep "which screws go in which holes" in order for reassembly.

However, the particular one shown seems like it probably just removes the inner can and that gives access to the inside of the junction box, with the outer case probably not being removable, though the description of *"Housing may be removed from plaster frame for junction box access"* is not entirely clear on that point.

Then again, the speaker holes themselves are pretty good access (and I've put at least one speaker in such a hole mostly for access, because it was cheaper than an access panel and was of some use there.) With a sectional rod (parts that screw together) to cross the space, more than 10 feet from the wall is not a huge barrier from a good-sized speaker hole.